# Java JTable "scrollRectToVisible" Bad Graphics?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to consectively scroll a JTable, and scroll to the given cell by index with the following code...

```
public void UpdateCurrentStep(final int index) {
    jTable1.setRowSelectionInterval(index, index);
    int viewPortIndex = index+3 > jTable1.getRowCount()-1 ? jTable1.getRowCount()-1 : index+3;
    jTable1.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(jTable1.getCellRect(viewPortIndex, 0, true)));
}
```

This scrolls like you would expect. However, occasionally when the JTable updates the graphics can get pretty bad and sometimes unreadable (Shown below).

Normal Refresh:
[image]

Bad Refresh:
[image]

The problem is inconsistent. Any ideas or suggestions how to fix this would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't show how the updates to the model and scrolling are done. Are you making sure that those changes are done in AWT event thread?

Comment: Have you reviewed the tutorial? _[How to Use Scroll Panes (The Java™ Tutorials > Creating a GUI With Swing > Using Swing Components)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)_.

Comment: @JustanotherJavaprogrammer Yes I confirmed it's getting executed on AWT Event Thread.

Comment: Post an [mre] demonstrating the problem. We can't guess what your application is doing.

Comment: I did a quick test, loading a file with 8150 lines and then paging through the table a screen full at a time without issue. Without a [mcve], there's not much more we can do for you

Answer (score 0):

By calling a manual repaint fixed the issue.

```
jTable1.setRowSelectionInterval(index, index);
int viewPortIndex = index+3 > jTable1.getRowCount()-1 ? jTable1.getRowCount()-1 : index+3;
jTable1.scrollRectToVisible(new Rectangle(jTable1.getCellRect(viewPortIndex, 0, true)));
jTable1.repaint();
```

It's probably not the cleanest solution but it worked in my case.